# creating groups based on multiple criteria in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 columns based on state-level demographics (gpd, per capita income, dti, unemployment rate and hpi), and a column with states. I would like to create a variable that contains 4 groups based on these demographic variables, so for example:

Group 1 would have values in the first quantile (worse demographics),
group 2 would be in the second quantile,
group 3 would be in the third quantile,
group 4 would be in the fourth quantile.

[image]

Here I just put a random number from 1 to 4 to indicate what the outcome should be. In the dataset I of course deal with more states, but this is roughly what it should look like.
So, in the end, every state would belong to a certain group, based on its demographics.
For all the variables it holds that the lower the value, the worse it is, except for unemployment rate of course.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the joint demographic quantiles based on the 5 variables?

Comment: Apologies, edited my question. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: What exactly defines the groups? In what group do you put someone who is in the first quantile of GDP but in the second of HPI? Under the assumption that every column is equally important you could standardize the columns, add them rowwise together (add the negative standardized Unemployment_rate) and then determine your groups based on the quartiles of this new column!

Comment: That's a nice idea, thanks!